# Sharing parameters between setting view and application view

Tags: iphone

Simple question : I've got an iPhone app with 2 views with each a separated xib files.
one view holds the settings of the app 
one view holds the app using the settings made in previous view.

How should I implement the sharing of setup parameters between the 2 views ?
should I manage those parameters in the app delegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the settings in the user defaults using

```
[[[NSUserDefaults] standardUserDefaults] setObject:blah forKey:@"blah"];
```

Then in the other view, just get the values from the user defaults with

```
[[NSUserDefaults] standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"blah"];
```

The NSUserDefaults class keeps the objects in memory and writes them out to disk at certain periods. So you don't have to worry about hitting the disk too often.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. Do you mean that the user will find back his settings when coming back later in the app ?

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefaults will write the settings to disk with a certain interval. It will also do this when the app terminates gracefully and when you call `[NSUserDefaults synchronise]`

You need to retrieve the values from the defaults using `objectForKey` and then update your UI accordingly.